# Image is in JPEG but Torchvision shows image extension is unsupported

Tags: image-processing, python-imaging-library, pytorch

I just resized the image dataset with Pillow and exported to JPEG with following steps:
Dataset is 1000K Celeb but I have taken few for testing propose.

```
img = img.crop([10, 10, 118, 118])
img = img.resize((image_size, image_size), Image.BILINEAR)
img.save(save_dir + img_list[i], 'JPEG')
```

Then I used torchvision's Imagefolder function to read data from folder

```
 mydata = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(data_path_here, transform=transform)
```

Image is exported in JPG format as expected but when tried to read the dataset from `torchvision`, it shows that file is not in JPEG format.
`RuntimeError: Found 0 files in subfolders of: Data/celeb_data/resized_celeb/`
`Supported extensions are: .jpg,.jpeg,.png,.ppm,.bmp,.pgm,.tif,.tiff,.webp`

OS: Ubuntu 18.04
IDE: Pycharm 19

Comment: Your question is lacking lots of details. You just resized the image dataset? Which image dataset? Where are the images? You did that with Pillow. How? And exported to JPEG. How? You tried to read it in `torchvision`. How? What OS, tool versions etc are you using?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have updated the question. To make you more clear, the images are resized successfully in JPG format as I can see properties of image as expected.
But When I use torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder function to read the images,it shows images are not in proper format.

Comment: The error message indicates it's unhappy with the filename extension, not the format. Are there files other than images in that directory?

Comment: @MarkRansom There are no other files inside the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to rename file extension in your code:

```
// img.save(save_dir + img_list[i], 'JPEG')
img.save(save_dir + img_list[i], 'jpeg')
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you get after checking the file type like this?

```
! apt install file
! file image.jpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to restructure the directory like this:

```
Data/celeb_data/resized_celeb/label_name: 
  - 1.jpg
  - 2.jpg
  ...
```

You can just discard the label after loading. This solve the problem for me. Hope it helps.